# Use PHP preg_match get a string between two other strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the variable `$Contents` that contains the contents of a webpage and I need to pull out the following:

Start: `<div class="XXXXX">`

End: `<div role="XXXXX"'`

The string represented by YYYYY could be numbers, characters, spaces, quotes and pretty much anything that exists on a modern keyboard.

Currently I am using this:

```
preg_match("/<div class=\"XXXXX\">(.*)<div role=\"XXXXX\"/", $Contents, $match);
echo "<p>Event Title: $match[1]</p>";
```

But getting nothing so I assume it's my regex that's the issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: what's YYYYY? I don't see that anywhere. what's a var_dump($match) show you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the second `XXXXX` should be `YYYYY`, or maybe you just mean it could be any string.

First, you really should use a parser instead of regex for this. See [this classic, sad tale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2057919) for the reason why.

Second, to answer your question: add a `?` after `.*` and use `s` after the final slash to match across lines, like this:

```
$Contents = '<div class="XXXXX">
    foo bar
    <div role="alacadabra">baz';
preg_match("/<div class=\"XXXXX\">(.*)<div role=\".+\"/s", $Contents, $match);
echo "<p>Event Title: $match[1]</p>"; // outputs foo bar
```